# Problema com expressão regular no asp.net com angularJS(1)

Tags: angularjs, asp.net, regex

Nesse site, eu peguei essa `regex`:

```
@"^\(?\d{2}\)?[\s-]?[\s9]?\d{4}-?\d{4}$"
```

Aí procurei adaptar para a minha realidade, minha regra que é: Só aceitar dígito(número) no input. Eu não sou lá essas coisas com `regex`, tenho dificuldade com ela. Fiz assim:

```
"^\[1-9]\d{2}\[2-9]\d{4}\[0-9]\d{4}$"
```

E me dá um erro de:

> Error: $parse:lexerr Lexer Error

Abri a página do AngularJS para saber qual é o erro e obtive isso:

> Lexer Error: Unexpected next at column{1} in expression [{2}].
>   Description Occurs when an expression has a lexical error, for example
>   a malformed number (0.5e-) or an invalid unicode escape.
>
> The error message contains a more precise error.
>
> To resolve, learn more about Angular expressions, identify the error
>   and fix the expression's syntax.

Como eu melhoro essa minha `regex`, obedecendo a minha regra? Só receber número e se houver 11 dígitos, o terceiro tem que ser 9.

Meu html ficou assim:

```
<label for="celular" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Celular</label>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <input id="celular" class="form-control input-sm" name="celular" type="tel" ng-model="vm.data.celular" ng-required="true"
                       ng-pattern="^\[1-9]\d{2}\[2-9]\d{4}\[0-9]\d{4}$" />
                <div class="message" ng-messages="form.celular.$error" ng-show="form.celular.$touched">
                    <div ng-message="required">Por favor, preencha o campo celular!</div>
                    <!--<div ng-message="minlength">O campo celular deve ter no m&iacute;nimo 11 caracteres.</div>
                    <div ng-message="maxlength">O campo celular deve ter no m&aacute;ximo 11 caracteres.</div>-->
                    <div ng-message="pattern">Formato de celular inválido Ex:11988887777</div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Antes eu validava min e max, mas não é preciso com uma `regex` assim, pois a própria `regex` já valida.

Mesmo eu colocando a `regex` postada pelo colega Mariano, eu digito qualquer número e o celular é validado. Veja como está:

```
<label for="celular" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Celular</label>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <input id="celular" class="form-control input-sm" name="celular" type="tel" ng-model="vm.data.celular" ng-required="true"
                       ng-pattern="[1-9]\d9?\d{8}" />
                <!--@"^\(?\d{2}\)?[\s-]?[\s9]?\d{4}-?\d{4}$"-->
                <div class="message" ng-messages="form.celular.$error" ng-show="form.celular.$touched">
                    <div ng-message="required">Por favor, preencha o campo celular!</div>
                    <!--<div ng-message="minlength">O campo celular deve ter no m&iacute;nimo 11 caracteres.</div>
                    <div ng-message="maxlength">O campo celular deve ter no m&aacute;ximo 11 caracteres.</div>-->
                    <div ng-message="pattern">Formato de celular inválido Ex:11988887777</div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Se eu coloco dessa forma, diz formato inválido para qualquer formato que eu digitar.
`ng-pattern="/^[1-9]\d9?\d{11}$/"`

Answer (score 0):

> Só receber número e se houver 11 dígitos, o terceiro tem que ser 9.

A seguinte expressão regular só aceitará 10 dígitos ou 11 dígitos começando com qualquer dígito, exceto `0`. Se houvesse 11 dígitos, o terceiro deve ser um `9`.

```
ng-pattern="/[1-9]\d9?\d{8}/"
```

Comment: Mariano, não consigo carregar a mensagem de erro para invalidar celular fora do padrão. Vou editar e colocar as mensagens de erro, caso o formato seja inválido.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi assim:

```
<label for="celular" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Celular</label>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <input id="celular" class="form-control input-sm" name="celular" type="text" ng-model="vm.data.celular" ng-required="true"
                       ng-pattern="/^[1-9]{2}\s?9\s?\d{8}$/" />
                <div class="message" ng-messages="form.celular.$error" ng-show="form.celular.$touched">
                    <div ng-message="required">Por favor, preencha o campo celular!</div>
                    <div ng-message="pattern">Formato de celular inválido Ex:11988887777</div>
                </div>
            </div>
```